# Reference to the target-file. Why/How is this created and used?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-codegen

I recently started out with Spring-Security and in this context found a project on [GitHub](https://github.com/ahmetbozok/spring-security-authentication-token-example) matching my interests.

While reading some code i discovered that a class (*facade\impl\UserFacadeImpl.java*) was linked to the target package. This means, when i run

- *mvn package*: the target-file is created and the import-link is valid
- *mvn clean*: the target-file is destroyed and my IDE marks the import-link as invalid

Imports from the target-directory and the class being used normally:

```java
import com.boza.swaggergen.model.Credential;
import com.boza.swaggergen.model.User;

public class UserFacadeImpl implements UserFacade {

    @Override
    public User createUser(final User user) {
        UserModel userModel = modelMapper.map(user, UserModel.class);
        userModel = userService.createUser(userModel);
        return modelMapper.map(userModel, User.class);
    }
```

The UserModel class shares the same fields with use User class, but the methods are different.

I have never seen anything like this and am completly baffled. I looked in the configuration files, but couldn`t find a hint where those classes are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those class are generated by [Swagger Codegen](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/). The general workflow is:

1. Describe [API](https://github.com/ahmetbozok/spring-security-authentication-token-example/blob/cd43d0862081afc0c73ad978f5d01a49780107d6/src/main/resources/swagger/login-api-definition.json#L1) using OpenAPI spec.
2. Configure Maven 's [POM](https://github.com/ahmetbozok/spring-security-authentication-token-example/blob/cd43d0862081afc0c73ad978f5d01a49780107d6/pom.xml#L97) to use [swagger-codegen-maven-plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) to generate the codes.
3. Generate codes by `mvn generate-sources` (`mvn package` will call it behind scene)
4. It only generates an abstract `@RestController` that is configured with  `@RequestMapping` and the request/response POJO for each API endpoint. You still have to implement the [actual logic](https://github.com/ahmetbozok/spring-security-authentication-token-example/blob/cd43d0862081afc0c73ad978f5d01a49780107d6/src/main/java/com/boza/controller/UserController.java#L16) by extending the generated `@RestController`.

Comment: I see, i found the description-files in the resources folder. Is it recommended to create the API this way?

Comment: It is about design first vs code first approach for REST API development . Both  have their pros and cons. There are already plenty of resources in Internet to talk about them .Maybe you can google about them to see which approach are more fit to you.